# AWS Using refresh token Javascript

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, refresh-token

Are there any examples on how to use the refresh token to get a new idtoken on aws cognito?

I´m trying to use http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminInitiateAuth.html

But then, it requires "developer credentials".

I think I was able to set that on Cognito following http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html#associate-developer-provider

Now I don´t know what else do I need to do on my code in order to handle such a developer credential?

This is the message I´m getting:

> "User:
>   arn:aws:sts::540029582710:assumed-role/Cognito_Skyline_User_Pool_ProdAuth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials
>   is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth on
>   resource:
>   arn:aws:cognito-idp:ap-northeast-2:540029582710:userpool/ap-northeast-2_7wGKApTQV"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, in the end, that I needed to call InitiateAuth instead of AdminInitiateAuth

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html